# Swift Generics : Custom closure with multiple arguments for filter function

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I have an caching array which can store different types of objects like UIViews, UICollectionReuableView, etc

```
var arrCache             = [AnyObject]()
```

I want to filter out these specific elements using built in filter function by passing a custom closure like this :

```
private func reusableViewsClosure<T where T: Equatable>(element : AnyObject, type: T) -> Bool {
    return element is T ? true : false
}
```

Now, when I call this closure on the filter function, I get an error stating

```
        let i = arrCache.filter(reusableViewsClosure(UIView))
```

**// error: Cannot convert call result type bool to expected type '(@noescape (Anyobject) throws -> Bool)'**

Just wondering if it is allowed to pass extra parameters for closures used for built in functions like map,flatmap, filter, etc because when I call the same function like this below, it works just fine:

```
private func reusableHeaderViewsClosure(element : AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return element is UICollectionReusableView ? true : false
}
...
let i = arrCache.filter(reusableHeaderViewsClosure)
```

Comment: What is `reusableViewsClosure(UIView)` trying to achieve?

Comment: `reusableViewsClosure(UIView)` is actually a generic closure for filering out elements based on specified type which in this case is UIView. I also wanted to pass UICollectionReusableView to the same function in order to avoid code duplication

Comment: But when you write `reusableViewsClosure(UIView)`, it's trying to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment syntax for this case will look like this:

```
let i = arrCache.filter { reusableViewsClosure($0, UIView) }
```

or a little more descriptive:

```
let i = arrCache.filter { object in
  return reusableViewsClosure(object, UIView)
}
```

I prefer first option for its compact size. If you really want to use `filer(closure)` syntax you can create factory returning closure (function currying).

```
func factory<T where T: Equatable>(type: T.Type) -> (AnyObject -> Bool) {
    return { reusableViewsClosure($0, type) }
}
```

with this you can use it for filter:

```
let i = arrCache.filter (factory(UICollectionView))
```